# Generation of XML with list of integers in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have an ID table. Right now I just need to generate a XML file as the following format. Actually, it is a list of integers.

```
--Target format
<ListOfIntegers>
    <Integer>150356</Integer>
    <Integer>150365</Integer>
</ListOfIntegers>
```

I tried to use this and many other ways,

```
SELECT  @tempXML = ( SELECT ID AS [Integer]
                    FROM    #tempIDTable
                    FOR XML PATH('ListOfIntegers'), ELEMENTS)
```

But it will only generate a XML file like

```
--Current format
<ListOfIntegers>
  <Integer>150356</Integer>
</ListOfIntegers>
<ListOfIntegers>
  <Integer>150365</Integer>
</ListOfIntegers>
```

What should I do?

Comment: This is a good question, worth an upvote! You state the input, the wrong output, the expected output and your own attempts. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempIDTable(ID INT);
INSERT INTO #tempIDTable VALUES(1),(2),(3);

DECLARE @tempXML XML;
SELECT  @tempXML = ( SELECT ID AS [Integer]
                    FROM    #tempIDTable
                    FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('ListOfIntegers'));

SELECT @tempXML;

DROP TABLE #tempIDTable;
```

The result:

```
<ListOfIntegers>
  <Integer>1</Integer>
  <Integer>2</Integer>
  <Integer>3</Integer>
</ListOfIntegers>
```